Beamer drawing shadow over top of the frame in Overleaf on iPad Chrome Browswer
So I went to recompile a presentation from 6 months ago on overleaf. Overleaf is running in the Chrome Browser for iPad OS 17.6.1. It compiled perfectly 6 months ago, but now the shadows are on top of the frame instead of behind it. Here’s a minimum working example:
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{boxes}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{An example frame}

    \begin{block}{Text that you can read}
        Lorum Ipsum.
    \end{block}


    Lorum Ipsum.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

And here is what this produces

Note that when I use the boxes theme, there is not this issue.
Any advice on what is going on would be appreciated.

Are you using safari? If yes, try to download the pdf and check locally.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Both 2023 and 2024 live versions display the same

Are you using safari?

I'm using Chrome, on an iPad. This bar doesn't exist when I download the pdf though, thank you

I don't have an ipad, so can't reproduce directly, but the current safari version on macOS has a problem with transparencies. I'll assume what you see is the same problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your help: changing the pdf viewer fixed the problem

might be related to https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/18634

Changing the overleaf PDF viewer from "Overleaf" to "Browser" fixed the issue, and downloading the pdf does not show the shadows over the frames, so this seems to be an issue with either the iPad OS or the iPad Chrome browser when displaying overleaf.
