Definition/Theorem environments have black boxes?
My compiler is set to LuaLaTeX. I'm wondering if anyone knows what causes the definition/theorem environments to look like this and what is the solution?
Here is my code:
%\documentclass{ctexart}

\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>
{
   \usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
  \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
% or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}


% On writeLaTeX, these lines give you sharper preview images.
% You might want to comment them out before you export, though.
\usepackage{pgfpages}

% \pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%
%   physical paper width=5.5in, physical paper height=5.5in]

\title[]{Fruits}
\author{Bob ross}
\institute{University of Fried Chicken}

\date[Aug 2022] % (optional)
{where I am presenting}
%\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{test}
      \begin{block}{Definition (orange)}
        is a color 
    \end{block}
    \begin{definition}
        asdfjlkjkl
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}




your code doesn't produce the output you show for me. but don't load inputenc. xcolor and graphicx are unnecessary. are you sure caption and subcaption work with beamer?

Please show your .log file so we can see which engine you use and which version of  beamer you have.

Ah, overleaf. I assume an apple device? Try a different pdf viewer.

Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/728981/36296

It turns out that the problem (at least one of them), is that I was using safari instead of something else. It does work just fine in Chrome!
Thanks to all for your help!
